# Javascript innerHTML with onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some AJAX, it pulls in the following, which is added to a `div` using `innerHTML`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('textareax').value += '\r\nTEST';">Add</a>
```

Then when I press the "Add" link, it will add "TEST" into `textareax`.

If I have it in the HTML of the document from the start, it works perfectly, but when I pull it in using AJAX and using `innerHTML` to add it to the `div` the "Add" link does not work.

I think it might be a problem because it has javascript in it and I am just adding it using `innerHTML`, but don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Can you show some more code, like how you do your Ajax request?

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure event binding doesn't work if you do that.  Can you create the DOM with createElement() and attach your event handler manually?  That's the way I always do it..

Comment: there has been a very similar question about this issue just yesterday. Check out the answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145244/why-doesnt-browser-parse-the-js-code-in-the-file-loaded-by-ajax/8145255. Maybe this can help you

Comment: Hmm nevermind, just tried it with innerHTML and events bind (Both IE and Firefox)..  I think you need to post more code!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r\n` is a newline, but is *parsed by JavaScript already*. The `innerHTML` will be set to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('textareax').value += '
TEST';">Add</a>
```

which does not work (a syntax error; JavaScript strings cannot have literal newlines).

You'd need to double-escape with `\\r\\n` so that it becomes `\r\n` when it is parsed by JavaScript (`\\` becomes `\` and the `r` will be unaffected). Then the `\r\n` will be kept in the `onclick` handler, so that the newline is indeed added to the textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/r6bhE/.

Comment: Thanks!  For future readers: I'm now using \\r\\n in the php output.  problem was I was not escaping the \r and \n in the php output.

Answer (score 1):

`onclick="javascript:document[...]` is incorrect syntax.  The onclick attribute is a javascript event, and doesn't need the javascript scheme indication.  You can just place the script directly into the attribute value:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('textareax').value += '\r\nTEST';">Add</a>
```

It's also a good idea to return a value when intercepting mouse events (`true` to pass the event on, `false` to cancel it).